# Django Navbar Categories Link Issues

Tags: python, django

When I click the categories link in the menu, I get the following error.

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/categorylist/
>
> Raised by:    post.views.post_detail
>
> No Post matches the given query.

**models.py**

```
def get_categorylist_url(self):
    return reverse('post:categorylist', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**views.py**

```
def post_categorylist(request, slug):

    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404()

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    post.categorylist()
    return redirect('post:categorylist')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('categorylist/',views.post_categorylist, name='categorylist'),
```

**header.html**

```
<li><a href="{% url 'post:categorylist' %}">Kategoriler</a></li>
```

**categorylist.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Test message.
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your root `urls.py` is as posted you should be going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/categorylist/ because that is the path the URL is linked to.

However, you've got a `slug` in your views but it isn't handled by your URLs so you might have a problem there as well. Because your view expects a slug, try changing your view to look for it;

```
path('categorylist/<slug:slug>/',views.post_categorylist, name='categorylist'),
```

Comment: I have navbar problem, the slug that I added on the HomeViews context is not working on the other views, how can I fix this? I don't want to add the same context on all the other views, is there any other way to solve this with DRY?

Comment: @DerekPK if you've got something that you want to be available to all views, you should consider a context processor; https://betterprogramming.pub/django-quick-tips-context-processors-da74f887f1fc

Comment: This seems good, but it only adds to one app at a time, is it possible to make one of these and every app gets them, or am I then using apps the wrong way?

Comment: It gets added to the context of every view that's part of an application using the settings file containing the context processor.

Comment: **@markwalker** I tested it and it seems like it got added to all the apps. Exactly what I hoped for. I added it to ***app1*** and then I went to a template in ***app2*** it worked the same.

Comment: @DerekPK That's right - they provide the data they return in all templates; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#context-processors

Answer (score 1):

Your error raised by: `post.views.post_detail` so your url is wrong.
You want get slug argument but your url hasn't any slug parameter. Firstly you should fix your url path.

Than, If you want when user click to x category link and get products in x category, let's make example:

Firstly create this view:

## views.py:

```
def category_list(request):
    # Category loops on index page.
    category_list = Category.objects.filter()
    context = {

        "category_list": category_list,
    }
    return context
```

Than, we should add this context to our context processor for accessing everywhere (because it is navbar, so navbar will be top of every page, right?)

## settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ************************************,
                'YOURMODELNAME.views.category_list',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Finally, you will access all categories on your project, just add this code on your template:

## navbar.html:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'categories' slug=category.slug %}">
        {{ category.name }} <!--You can use ul-li for displaying them-->
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Ok, we displayed our categories, but when user click any link, should redirect to filtered list in clicked category. So we should create page and link for this page:

## views.py:

```
def category_list(request, slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)    
    posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
    context = {
        "posts": posts, #filtered products
    }
    return render(request, "posts_in_category.html", context)
```

## urls.py:

```
path('category/<slug:slug>', views.category_list, name="category_list")
```

## posts_in_category.html:

```
{% for post in posts_in_category %}
        {{ post.name }}
    {% endfor %}
```

If you miss anything, I can explain in Turkish ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this codes. How do I add links?

**views.py**

```
def categorylist(request):
    # Category loops on index page.
    categorylist = Category.objects.filter()
    context = {

        "categorylist": categorylist,
    }
    return render(request, "post/categories.html", context)
```

**categories.html**

```
{% for post in categorylist %}
  {{ post.name }}
{% endfor %}
```